# how to use bluetooth in android throughout different activity without connecting and disconnecting the socket?

Tags: android, android-activity, bluetooth, bluetooth-socket

I am trying to make an app in which several activity requires communication with bluetooth module. So for now i am doing it by making and disconnecting RFCOMM connection while entering the activity and leaving respectively.
But i want to have a continuous without any break. 
is it possible in android? if yes than how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could place your Bluetooth work in a service that all your activities make use. You'd need to do some work on synchronization as your one service will need to track which activity made which requests and can keep their data separate.